# PHP + MySQL : Select related records from other tables and link to a different php page

Tags: php, mysql

I got a schools php list page. The page will display the list of schools from the main MySQL table(schools)(pk). I want to add a button in the lists that links to an other php page. The other php page will display data from other related table(add_info)(fk).

Now, I'm using these codes for my index.php page:

```
    $sql = "SELECT school.sid AS ID, school.name AS name GROUP BY school.sid desc LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
}

$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
```

This is my newly added button but I can't get it to work as it's from another table :

```
<?php
        if($f["schoolstaff"]=="")
        {
        ?>
        <img src="images/nostaff.png"  />
        <?php
        }
        else
        {
        ?>  
        <a href= "<?php echo $f["schoolstaff"];?>" target="_blank" </a><img src="images/staff.png" width="77" height="26" />
            <?php
        }
        ?>





       <?php
       if($cek=="no")
       {
       ?>
       <table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
           <td>SORRY, NO RESULTS FOUND.</td>
         </tr>
       </table>
       <?php
       }
    //}
```

I'm still a beginner in php and I couldn't find the way to check the data from the other related table whether it's empty or not. How could I do it and link it to the addinfo_school.php with the same schoolid ? Thank you very much :)

Comment: I fail to see how your first query would work. You're selecting two fields without specifying a table. you'd need at least a `FROM school` in there...

Answer (score 0):

you almost had it.

The solution depends on the method of passing the `schoolid` to `addinfo_school.php`:

Method 1 `GET`:

To do this you should use a `a` tag similar to this:

```
<a href="addinfo_school.php?schoolid=<?php echo $schoolid?>" target="_blank"><img src="images/staff.png" width="77" height="26" /></a> // $schoolid is a php variable where you have the id you want to pass. Also notice the `img` tag is inside the `a` tag.
```

On the `addinfo_school.php` you would receive this variable like this:

```
$schoolid=$_GET['schoolid'];
```

Method 2 `POST`:

to do this you should use javascript/jquery to send the variable via POST, or use a FORM. If you need more info on this one just ask me, but it's a bit longer.

To receive the variable in `addinfo_school.php`:

```
$schoolid=$_POST['schoolid'];
```